# Detecting uiswitch change and running code accordingly

Tags: ios, xcode, uiswitch

I want to have three different switches. When I click the first switch I want to make the other 2 go off. The same goes for the next two. I want to sense if it has been changed and then run the code for that switch. I declared the switches as outlets in the .h file and hooked them up properly. Is this possible? If so how may i go about doing it? I have a tried a couple of things but in order to work i need to only run the code when one of the switches changes. Otherwise the logic does not work properly.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you need to add a target/action for `UIControlEventValueChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect a `UISwitch` to an action method just as you could a `UIButton`, so hook up your switches in your .xib file and add this code to your implementation file:

```
-(void)switchChanged {
    //Common code that is performed for all switches
}

-(IBAction)switch1:(id)sender {    //Hook up to switch 1 in your xib
    [self switchChanged];
    //Insert switch 1 specific code here
}

-(IBAction)switch2:(id)sender {    //Hook up to switch 2 in your xib
    [self switchChanged];
    //Insert switch 2 specific code here
}

-(IBAction)switch3:(id)sender {    //Hook up to switch 3 in your xib
    [self switchChanged];
    //Insert switch 3 specific code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked like a charm. I didn't realize that switches could have actions too.

Comment: Actually there is a weird problem. When i click it works fine. When i slide it doesn't. i think this is cause i chose touch up inside but i was wondering whether there was a better choice that i should make?

Comment: @aviators54 You should use "Value Changed" instead of "Touch Up Inside."

Comment: thank you for your help. I feel dumb that i didn't figure this out before but i tried like 20 ways and was stumped